# JavaScript persist a search query through out the whole site

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm currently fetching a query (e.g, `http://localhost:49781/HTML/index.html?inputName=Marcus`) from a html form using this following JavaScript:

```
function setSignedName() {
    if (window.location.search.indexOf("=") >= 0) {
        var split = window.location.search.split("=");
        document.getElementById("signed_in_name").innerHTML += split[1];
    } else {
        document.getElementById("signed_in_name").innerHTML = "Not signed in";
    }
```

running the script will get the result: Marcus.

I want this string to be persisted through out my site, so when the user navigates to another page the inputName will still be Marcus.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Edit: This approach is only for display/non-production use, I know using a server side language like PHP is the best approach.

Comment: try looking at using local storage http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best way is using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Local_Storage). It [works in all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage) and it's easy to use:

```
function setSignedName() {
    var userName = "";

    if (window.location.search.indexOf("=") >= 0) {
        var split = window.location.search.split("=");
        userName += split[1];
    } else {
        userName = "Not signed in";
    }

    document.getElementById("signed_in_name").innerHTML = userName;
    localStorage.setItem("userName", userName);
}
```

To access it:

```
var userName = localStorage.getItem("userName");
```

And this is it. Check for it in the Resources tab in Developer tools(F12) in your fav broswer.

Comment: Yes, I know that using a server side language is optimal, but this is strictly for display/non-production use. I'll try this out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to either repopulate it through GET parameters in your server side language, or if you want to hack it together, use a cookie and repopulate it with JavaScript on page load with "pushState".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState()_method